# Foreach Loop to Create Multiple Shortcuts Not Working as Expected

Tags: powershell, foreach, shortcut

I'm trying to make a script that creates multiple shortcuts to executables on the desktop. Because the code that's responsible for creating the shortcuts will be used multiple times and in other scripts I decided to put it into a function.

The logic is pretty straightforward:

- Define function
- Define target files of shortcuts in separate arrays (I'm using `notepad.exe` and `cmd.exe` in my example)
- Define intended path for shortcuts

I'm trying to use nested foreach loops to iterate through the target file and shortcut path arrays but it's not producing the shortcuts correctly. Maybe there's a better way to iterate through the programs that I'm not seeing (quite possible as I'm sick and have bad brain fog).

The script can handle one shortcut at least.

I've tried running the function code outside of the function. When I remove Command Prompt from the arrays, the shortcut to Notepad is properly created.

```
function CreateShortcuts {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)]
        [System.String]$ShortcutPath,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 1)]
        [System.String]$TargetFile,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, Position = 2)]
        [System.String]$ShortcutArgs
    )

    $objShell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
    $objShortcut = $objShell.CreateShortcut($ShortcutPath)
    $objShortcut.TargetPath = $TargetFile
    $objShortcut.Save()
}

$TargetFiles = "$env:SystemRoot\System32\notepad.exe", "$env:SystemRoot\System32\cmd.exe"
$ShortcutPaths = "$env:Public\Desktop\Notepad.lnk", "$env:Public\Desktop\Command Prompt.lnk"

foreach ($ShortcutPath in $ShortcutPaths) {
    foreach ($TargetFile in $TargetFiles) {
        CreateShortcuts -ShortcutPath $ShortcutPath -TargetFile $TargetFile
    }
}
```

Expected output is shortcuts to Notepad and Command Prompt appear on the desktop and link to the intended program. Instead what happens is both shortcuts link to `cmd.exe`.

Comment: You're running CreateShortcuts 4 times and the last two are pointing to cmd.exe.

Comment: As sidenote: When using Com objects, always clean-up when finished with them. `[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($objShell) | Out-Null; [System.GC]::Collect(); [System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers(); $objShell = $null`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the input everyone. It was helpful and got me unstuck. My brain fog cleared the next day and the gears in my head finally started turning again. I ended up using hashtables for this task to ensure that the targets, shortcut paths, and shortcut arguments values all match up based on a key of the same name. I realized using arrays could be problematic if the values for each of the above were indexed out of order from one another, or some shortcuts needed arguments while others didn't.

Below is the updated code. The only thing left to do is add the help information.

```
    function CreateShortcuts {

    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true,
                   Position = 0)]
        [System.Collections.Hashtable]$TargetFiles,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true,
                   Position = 1)]
        [System.Collections.Hashtable]$ShortcutPaths,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false,
                   Position = 2)]
        [System.Collections.Hashtable]$ShortcutArgs
    )


    $objShell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell

    Foreach ($item in $TargetFiles.Keys) {

        $objShortcut = $objShell.CreateShortcut($ShortcutPaths.Item($item))
        $objShortcut.TargetPath = $TargetFiles.Item($item)
        if ($ShortcutArgs)  {
            $objShortcut.Arguments = $ShortcutArgs.Item($item)
        }
        $objShortcut.Save()
    }
}


$TargetFiles = @{
                    "Notepad" = "$env:SystemRoot\System32\notepad.exe"
                    "CmdPrompt" = "$env:SystemRoot\System32\cmd.exe"
                }

$ShortcutPaths = @{
                      "Notepad" = "$env:Public\Desktop\Notepad.lnk"
                      "CmdPrompt" = "$env:Public\Desktop\Command Prompt.lnk"
                  }

$ShortcutArgs = @{
                     "CmdPrompt" = "/foo -bar"
                     "Notepad" = "/test"
                 }

CreateShortcuts -ShortcutPaths $ShortcutPaths -TargetFiles $TargetFiles -ShortcutArgs $ShortcutArgs
```

Answer (score 0):

You're doing your loops wrong. What you are doing is looping through each item in `$ShortcutPaths`, and for each of those looping through each item in `$TargetFiles`, so every item in `$ShortcutPaths` ends up with a shortcut created pointing at the last item in `$TargetFiles`. What you want to do instead is correlate each item in each array with the same indexed item in the other array. So item 1 in `$ShortcutPaths` with item 1 in `$TargetFiles`, and so on. To do that you use a `For` loop as such:

```
$TargetFiles = "$env:SystemRoot\System32\notepad.exe", "$env:SystemRoot\System32\cmd.exe"
$ShortcutPaths = "$env:Public\Desktop\Notepad.lnk", "$env:Public\Desktop\Command Prompt.lnk"
For($i=0;$i -lt $ShortcutPaths.count;$i++){
    CreateShortcuts -ShortcutPath $ShortcutPaths[$i] -TargetFile $TargetFiles[$i]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I agreed with TheMadTechnician, simply add another variable $i to select from the strings array you provide. can be also written like that:

```
$i=0    
    Foreach ($TargetFile in $TargetFiles) {

        CreateShortcuts -ShortcutPath $ShortcutPaths[$i] -TargetFile $TargetFile
        $i=$i+1

    }
```

I prefer to have this for loop inside the function section and you simply pass the string array to the function. Something like this.

```
function CreateShortcuts {

    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)]
        [system.String[]]$TargetFile,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 1)]
        [system.String[]]$ShortcutPath,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, Position = 2)]
        [System.String]$ShortcutArgs
    )
        $i=0
        Foreach ($object in $TargetFile) {
            $objShell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
            $objShortcut = $objShell.CreateShortcut($ShortcutPath[$i])
            $objShortcut.TargetPath = $object
            $objShortcut.Save()
            $i=$i+1
            }

}


$TargetFile = "$env:SystemRoot\System32\notepad.exe", "$env:SystemRoot\System32\cmd.exe"
$ShortcutPath ="$env:Public\Desktop\Notepad.lnk" ,"$env:Public\Desktop\Command Prompt.lnk"

CreateShortcuts  -TargetFile $TargetFile -ShortcutPath $ShortcutPath
```